# Best practice for `pip install` red warnings?

Tags: python, pip

I have it many times that when installing with pip I get success messages followed by *red* lines with warnings. An example:

> Successfully built qgrid
>
> spacy 2.0.11 has requirement regex==2017.4.5, but you'll have regex 2017.11.9 which is incompatible.
>
> proto-google-cloud-vision-v1 0.90.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
>
> proto-google-cloud-speech-v1beta1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.
>
> proto-google-cloud-spanner-v1 0.15.3 has requirement oauth2client<4.0dev,>=2.0.0, but you'll have oauth2client 4.1.2 which is incompatible.

How do I reconcile the state of the install in such cases? do these messages simply imply that older versions will be used so that the compatibility of previously installed packages will preserve? does it also imply that the newly installed package has requested newer versions and may or may not work well, with the old ones present?

How do you usually proceed in these cases?

Obviously working with virtual environments may remove the clashes, but I can see this happening also in virtual environments.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In these case, try :

```
py -m name_of_your_initial_package install --upgrade name_of_your_initial_package.
```

name_of_your_initial_package* example: proto-google-cloud-vision-v1

Full example :

```
py -m proto-google-cloud-vision-v1 install --upgrade proto-google-cloud-vision-v1
```

To do that you need to install your package with pip before :

```
py -m pip install proto-google-cloud-vision-v1
```